# Esxi доменная аутентификация не работает при том что работает root а также сквозная доменная аутентификация

Tags: vmware

Есть Esxi хост 5.1, добавленный в домен. Прекрасно работала доменная аутентификация. Потом что то случилось и теперь работает только root аутентификация, а так же доменная сквозная аутентификация если заходишь с vSphere Client ставишь галочку Использовать текущую уч запись Windows аутентификацию. То есть, если вбиваешь логин domain\user в поле вручную - то не работает, он долго думает, висит и конец. Кто виноват и что делать, есть идеи у кого ? спасибо.

Что уже делал:
Вывел и вогнал esxi хост в домен снова

Проверил группу через которую связывается Esxi с ActiveDirectory (точнее пересоздал её заново)

Проверил вкладку Permissions Tab в Esxi где даются разрешения пользователям домена для управления esxi

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, после переустановки сертификатов а так же после перезагрузки ESXi хоста всё заработала. Скорее это глюк неинтересный.